# Sourcing bash_prompt (bash script) when running zsh (oh-my-zsh)

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have a theme that is written in `bash` (I think). However, I have decided to use `zsh` for my shell. More specifically, I'm using oh-my-zsh (a customised `zsh` I believe).

The theme I want to use is currently in a file called `.bash_prompt`, which was being sourced from `.bash_profile` back when the default shell was `bash`.

Is there anyway I can tell oh-my-zsh to use this prompt? I understand that `zsh` has a slightly different syntax/language to `bash`, so sourcing it directly from `.zshrc` throws quite a lot of errors.

Comment: Can you show us that "theme" from `.bash_prompt`? Which errors are shown specifically?

Comment: [Here we are.](https://github.com/necolas/dotfiles/blob/master/bash/bash_prompt) Here are the errors: `.dotfiles/bash/bash_prompt:44: parse error near `]]'`

Comment: Those double brackets are test commands. ( See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS ). You might want to replace that that single brackets or /bin/test (which is the same as a single bracket).

Comment: Right, the next error I have is this: `.dotfiles/bash/bash_prompt:47: = not found`. Seems to be a few small differences between `zsh` and `bash` like this, would be nice if they were documented in one place somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you generally can't source non-trivial `bash` scripts in `zsh` without some modification.

The Z-Shell is most similar to the [Korn Shell [`ksh`]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korn_shell), while `bash` is a superset of the [Bourne shell [`sh`]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell).

There are some [syntax differences](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq02.html#21) between `sh` and `ksh` shells. Although `bash` and `zsh` have considerable [feature crossover](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq02.html#25), implementation details do differ in some respects.

This is particularly noticeable with the `if [[ "$VAR" ]];` constructs used in the linked script (they don't seem to work in `zsh` - `if [ $VAR ];` does, though).

However, the modification needed to get the linked script sourced by `zsh` is pretty minimal.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So are these shells referred to as languages?